# Calling a Apex Function after VF page is rendered

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am having a visual force page rendered as PDF with a list displaying the data. I want to update the values of the object from which my list values are coming. How can I update the object values after the page has completed loading.
I am getting the list values from the Get method So DML is not allowed in that method. 
Is there any way to update values after page is rendered as PDF.

Please provide some example if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the action attribute of the [apex:page][1] component. Mention the function name in the action attribute and the function will load after the page is rendered.

```
   public List<CanaryAMS__Carrier_Quotes__c> getcarrierSubmissionlist(){

      carrierSubmissionDatalist = [select CanaryAMS__Carrier__r.Name, CanaryAMS__Carrier_Product__r.Name ,CanaryAMS__Quote__c , CanaryAMS__Notes__c , CanaryAMS__Insurance_Quote__c
                                    from CanaryAMS__Carrier_Quotes__c where CanaryAMS__Insurance_Quote__c = :quoteId and CanaryAMS__Ischecked__c = true ];


     return carrierSubmissionDatalist;
   }


   public List<CanaryAMS__Carrier_Quotes__c> checkAndRedirect(){

    carrierSubmissionDatalist1 = [select CanaryAMS__Carrier__r.Name, CanaryAMS__Carrier_Product__r.Name ,CanaryAMS__Quote__c , CanaryAMS__Notes__c , CanaryAMS__Insurance_Quote__c
                                    from CanaryAMS__Carrier_Quotes__c where CanaryAMS__Insurance_Quote__c = :quoteId and CanaryAMS__Ischecked__c = true ];



   system.debug('QuoteComparisionlist ==== >> '+ carrierSubmissionDatalist1);

    for(CanaryAMS__Carrier_Quotes__c cq: carrierSubmissionDatalist1) 
      {
           CanaryAMS__Carrier_Quotes__c data1 = new CanaryAMS__Carrier_Quotes__c();

             data1.id = cq.id;
             data1.CanaryAMS__Ischecked__c = false;

            system.debug('Dummy Data== '+ data1);
            update data1;

      }
    return carrierSubmissionDatalist1;

    }
```

VisualForce Page:

```
  <apex:page showHeader="false" Controller="QuoteComparisionPreview"        renderas="pdf" action="{!checkAndRedirect}">
   <c:CompareQuotesRenderedPDF quoteId="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.quoteId}" />
 </apex:page>
```

component:

```
 <apex:component Controller="QuoteComparisionPreview" allowDML="true" rendered="true" >
  <apex:attribute name="quoteId" type="String" description="Parent record where attachment would be attached"/>

<apex:pageBlock title="Related Carrier Submission" >
                      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!carrierSubmissionlist}" var="cq" border="1"  width="100%">                     
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Carrier</apex:facet>
                                      {!cq.CanaryAMS__Carrier__r.Name}
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Carrier product</apex:facet>
                                       {!cq.CanaryAMS__Carrier_Product__r.Name}
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Quote Amount</apex:facet>
                                      {!cq.Quote__c}
                        </apex:column>

                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Notes</apex:facet>
                                      {!cq.Notes__c}
                        </apex:column>

                     </apex:pageBlockTable>  
             </apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: adding the action attribute on the apex:page doesn't work as it reloaded the page and the updated records are displayed. I need the page to show the old records not the updated records. records should update after the page displayed the old records.

Comment: Maybe you can have 2 separate lists - one to show on page and one to update.

Comment: yes I am using 2 separate lists but how should I call the method for update after the page data is displayed?

Comment: The list to show on page will be created in constructor. During that same time, you also create another list. In the function that is called from action, update the second list. If you are already following this approach and still the page is displaying new records, you can try moving all the logic (creating the list and updating) in the function called from action attribute.

Comment: Rajesh

I have edited the question now can you assist me where I am wrong?

Comment: what is your objective? you show old records on page load.  and then immediately show new records? no manual intervention between these 2 displays?

Comment: sfdcFanBoy:

I just want to update the CanaryAMS__Carrier_Quotes__c Ischecked values to false after the 2nd page is loaded completed and also an email is sent with the Pdf rendered page. I short I want to execute checkAndRedirect on completion of all the code.

Comment: Looking at the code, your apex:pageblocktable refers to the checkAndRedirect function and hence it will show the updated values. Shouldn't it refer to the getcarrierSubmissionlist?

Comment: Rajesh,

That is not a issue I have posted the code in hurry.

Comment: Do this then. Query the carrierSubmissionDatalist in the checkAndRedirect method before you do the update. It seems the getcarrierSubmissionlist is getting called after the checkAndRedirect is been called.